# Is it possible to use proxies to change ports in this way?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, hosting

I am new to SysAdmining if you can even call it that. Basically me and the homies are running a minecraft server. But we don't want to pay the premium to get port 25565 which is super expensive for some reason.

Is it possible to get some kind of proxy, that takes in xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:23974 or similar and outputs yyyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:25565. That way I don't have to pay the premium for dedicated IP.

Soo sorry if this is a stupid question. I thought this was the place where you guys would know it anyone did.

Answer (score 1):

Though not completly the answer you were asking for - AFAIK minecraft can use `SRV` dns records to alter the default port in a transparent way, I believe you can use it to run the server on a custom port and not having issue with typing the port in minecraft clients each time. You can also use it to run multiple world on the same IP and connect to each by using a different fqdn.
the records looks like this :

`_minecraft._tcp.name TTL class SRV priority weight port target`

in the link below you also have some examples, I'm sure that with enough fiddling you will get it to work
https://www.mcmiddleearth.com/community/wiki/setting-up-a-srv-record/